# How do I stop autonumber in a table spiralling out of control?

Tags: ms-access

I'm using an append query to import records from table 1 to table 2. Table 2 has an autonumber field that I use to generate a primary key. I have a composite key on 4 fields in table 2 that stops duplicate records being imported from table 1. When I run the append query it says it's going to add 200k records but then only imports the 5k records that are new. All fine except that the autonumber in table 2 jumps to start 195k higher for the new records.

I've looked at playing around with joins to get the append query to only pull the new 5k records from table 1 in the first place but the only combinations I can see all seem to include all records from one of the tables. What's the simplest way of avoiding the autonumber spiraling out of control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Import to a (temp) table having your composite key but no AutoNumber.
- Copy the ~5K records from that table to your Table2.

Or:

Set the ID not as AutoNumber.

After every import, update the (empty) IDs manually.

Comment: Thanks. How would you identify the new 5k records to then copy them?

Comment: Leave the ID as _Null_ or perhaps 0 (zero) as default value.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay in replying and the question I'm about to ask - long day. Are you suggesting I import all the records into a temp table and then only copy out the 5k new ones? Or are you suggesting I only copy in the 5k records and then copy them out again? In either case how do I identify the 5k new records from table 1 or the temp table? I note you suggest leaving as Null or 0 but how does this help me compare table 1/temp table to table 2 to find the new records?

Comment: How about if I replicate table 2 in a temp table without an autonumber with an additional field with every record as "1". I then run an append query which imports the only the new records without filling in the additional field. I then run an update query to delete all the old table 2 records and run  another append query to add these to table 2. Was your way simpler and I'm just being thick? (highly likely)

Comment: I think my second suggestion will be the simplest to implement.

Comment: Ok but I'm not actually sure what you mean! Could you give me a little more detail, maybe step by step?

Comment: Do as you do now, just don't have the ID set to AutoNumber. Specify a default value for the ID of 0 or Null. After adding records, update the IDs to have sequential numbers starting from the last used ID + 1.